# Binary executable for changing directory-docker

Tags: docker, exec, cd

I need to run some comments inside a docker container

```
docker exec -i -t mycontainer cd /root/myfolder
```

It is showing that

```
exec: "cd": executable file not found in $PATH
```

So cd is not a binary executable but it is implemented as a shell built-in

Is there any alternative to "cd" for changing directory as executable or is there any other way to execute change directory command with docker?

Answer (score 0):

What do you use as a base image for your container? `cd` usually is not a `bash` or `sh` builtin but a command on its own. Did you try that also by providing the full path to the `cd` command (like `/usr/bin/cd`)? By the way that command makes no sense on its own. It would execute the `cd` in the containers environment and then end. The information that you changed into that directory is lost, then.

Comment: i need to run a script which is inside the container, so i need to change the directory(say /root/myfolder) to one that contains the script and then run it.Don't tell me to run the script by running source /root/myfolder/myscript.sh ,bcoz the script already some relative path information. Hope you understood my scenario ..

Comment: In that case you could do something like: `docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/cd /root/myfolder && ./script.sh"`

Comment: Does that folder exist? Did you verify that? You still did not gave the information about what you use as your base image. When I do this simple test with an official ubuntu image that works fine: `docker run -it ubuntu sh -c "cd /root && pwd"`

Comment: My base image is symdrive.It may not be familiar to you.I can run docker exec -i -t mycontainer /bin/bash   then run cd /root/myfolder and run ./myscript.sh  by hand. so the directory exist there.

Comment: Ok then. In your question you wrote that `cd` is builtin as a shell addon. I indeed do not know *symdrive*. But assuming that `cd` is known by the `/bin/bash` that you use and also assuming that your `bash` has the standard `-c` option, what about the following invocation: `docker exec -it mycontainer /bin/bash -c "cd /root/myfolder && ./myscript.sh"`?